# Generate all possible combinations from given characters and length (wordlist)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, combinations

I have a string like "abc".

Now I want to get all possible combinations of this characters:\

"aaa"
"aab"
"aac"
"aba"
...
"ccc"

How can I do this in java?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I really don't know where to start.
I've googled a bit but the answers I could find I really didn't understand how they work and/or how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a psuedocode, not java.

```
char = {a,b,c} 
l = 3

for(i = 0;i<l;i++)
 for(j = 0;j<l;j++)
   for(k = 0;k<l;k++)
     print(char[i],char[j],char[k],"\n")
   end for
 end for
end for
```

Please share if it works/not/understandable.

Comment: This works if and only if the length of the char array is always 3.

Comment: I just want to answer the "really don't know where to start" part.. the rest/chg/upgrade I'll leave in to the OP.